# how to access User's full name

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a project for school where I need the full name of the user which I will display in the sidebar in my app. I tried following:

```
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
int position = c.getPosition();
if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
        String columnName = columnNames[j];
        //nameView.setText(columnName);

    }
}
c.close();
```

from multiple forums I found on stack overflow but whenever I open the activity called shape, the app just crashes.

there is a permission called get account or something like that but I don't know how to use it and I couldn't find it either.

Comment: did you add permission of READ_Contacts in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

`GET_ACCOUNTS` was moved into the `CONTACTS` permission group in Android 6.0. So you need to request contact permission. To request for any permission you can use the below code

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
}
```

Once you do that, for devices with API >=23 You will get popup at runtime and then once the user accepts the permission or rejects it, your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method is called. so here you will have to handle your check whether user granted the app the permission. If yes you can continue with your logic

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            boolean isPerpermissionForAllGranted = false;
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions.length==grantResults.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                    }else{
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=false;
                    }
                }

                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now get user account");
            } else {
                isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied");
            }
            if(isPerpermissionForAllGranted){
               // do your stuff here
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

To get user details you can do the following as well -

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
```

Comment: thanks a lot but when i put my code where you told me to put it into your code, i get a value of "android name " which is assigned to the string[] c, but i want it to show the name of the user. i treid running this on my phone thinking it might a problem in the emulator but had no luck. any suggestions?

Comment: it does work. im sorry but i dont really know what you are doing with that code. when i add it to my program, everything is red, and my app doesnt compile either

Comment: Which part of the code. Taking permissions or getting user name?

Comment: in the second code that you provided, all the blue parts are red, and when i run it , i get nothing. also, when i ran the first code you gave me, i got "android name" is there a fix to that?

Comment: How to use the second part code, refer to https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-google-integration-and-login-tutorial/

Comment: There is no name to fix that. If the user hasn't names his device then you will always gent android name. The most sure shot way is to see which google account is signed in on device and get the name from that which is done in second part of code